# How do I limit the features shown in attribute table to those in the current time range?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, temporal-controller

I loaded a vector layer with temporal information and set up the Temporal properties accordingly. The Temporal Controller lets me view temporally filtered subsets of my data according to its current time range.

How do I limit the features shown in the attribute table to just the features intersecting the current time range?

Comment: It does not look possible just now (tested with 3.14.15-Pi). The @map_start_time and map_end_time variables that can be used to create titles with the time in them are not available in the filter expression. Probably a feature request. As a work around using the filter "Show Features Visible On Map" might help.

Comment: Thanks! I found this feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39076